# Cannot read ob_flush() trough ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a code where I make an AJAX request at a certain file whenever I click  a button, the request is as follows:

```
$("#syncDNS").click(function(){
    $('#status').html("");
    $('#status').addClass('loading');

    function updateProgress(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php',
            success: function(data){
                $('#status').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?action=sync',
        success: function (response) {
            clearInterval(loop);
            $('#status').removeClass('loading');
            if(response){
                $('#status').addClass('alert alert-warning').html("<h4>Aviso</h4>" + response);
            }else{
                $('#status').addClass('alert alert-success').html("<h4>Sucesso</h4>" + "DNS sincronizado com sucesso!");
            }
        }
    });

    updateProgress();
    var loop = setInterval(function () {
        updateProgress(); 
    }, 1000);
});
```

In the code I make the request, and while I wait for it's success I keep running in a loop another function to update the progress of the first one.
And in my index.php file I have:

```
require_once(CONTROLLER_PATH . "ControleAutodns.php");
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';

switch ($action) {

   ...

   case 'sync':
           $controller = ControleAutodns::getInstance();
           $return = $controller->syncDNS();
           exit($return);
           break;
   ...

}
```

In the index I include my control file and call the PHP function, this php function is a loop, where I add some entries to a database:

```
public function syncDNS(){

...

   foreach($result as $row) {
               $current ++;
               echo($current);

   ...

   }

...

return $string;
}
```

The thing is, the requests are working as intended and the PHP function is also doing it's job, I just can't listen to the echo's in the syncDNS function, why is that? I also tried using ob_start(), ob_flush(), flush(), but nothing worked.
As I understand, the control file is included in the index, so anything echoed in there should be available trough an AJAX POST request.

Comment: Do you see the echos' when calling the php file in your browser?

Comment: No, neither in the response from the requests or in the page.

Comment: Then leave the ajax aside, focus on debugging the php parts. Eg. does $result contain any rows and the foreach loop gets executed?

Comment: Are PHP sessions involved, using the file system as the session storage? Then it might be the “typical” case of the session file write lock blocking your concurrent requests, the solution to that is to call `session_write_close` as soon as possible in the long running script.

Comment: So, the PHP is working as intended, my function is going trough all the rows, and when I return my final variable all the echos are returned with it.
And I'm not using PHP sessions.

Comment: You wrote both " I just can't listen to the echo's in the syncDNS function " and now in a comment "all the echos are returned with it". I am confused as to what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Ok, so, my function runs in a loop, and I want to know how many times the function has looped, so I echo a simple counting variable every time I loop. But I can't read these while the function is running, I just receive then all at the end, with the expected response. So I get my echoes, but just after the function has already finished running. Which is useless for me.